# jQuery escape period in id

Tags: javascript, jquery

According to [this page](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) this should work. Here is the code and the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karl1coleman/kz0gbtqL/3/).

```
<input id="id.docType" value="45"/>
<br/>
<p></p>
<input id="thevalue" />

var str = 'id.docType';
str = str.replace('.', '\\\\.');
var selector = '#' + str;
$('p').text(selector);
var x = $(selector).val();
$('#thevalue').val(x);
```

Any ideas why this doesn't work? I have ids that have periods and trying to use them as a selector with jQuery. jQuery's page says I should be able to escape the period with 2 back slashes but it isn't working.

Comment: you're escaping too many times.

Comment: `str = str.replace('.', '\\.');`. That page you refered too also says it: _as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slash is double escaped, it only needs escaped once:

```
str = str.replace('.', '\\.');
```

Comment: I swear I tried that in my app AND in the jsfiddle and it didn't work. Does now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
str = str.replace('.', '\\\\.');
```

to

```
str = str.replace('\.', '\\.');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/kz0gbtqL/4/)**